# Writing PDF to a browser failing in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, pdf

I'm trying to read a PDF from a URL and display it to a user's browser (via the passed in 'response' object). I've tried to use the code below and it works sometimes, but generally fails:

```
function writePdfToBrowser(url, response) {
    http.get(url, function(res) {
        logger.verbose('about to start download...');
        var chunks = [];
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            chunks.push(chunk);
        });
        res.on("end", function() {
            logger.verbose('downloaded');
            var buffer = new Buffer.concat(chunks);
            //write downloaded pdf to the original response
            response.write(buffer);
            //response.send(buffer);
            response.end();
        });
    }).on("error", function() {
        logger.error("error!");
    });
}
```

In the new page where I attempted to load the pdf it would just say "Failed to load pdf".

I'm new to Node, so not sure where the problem lies, any ideas? Anyone have any working code to do the same thing?

Thank you for any help!

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use piping:

```
function pipe(url, res) {   
    var request = http.get(url, function(response) {
        res.writeHead(response.statusCode, response.headers)
        response.pipe(res); 
    });

    request.on('error', function(error){
        res.statusCode = 500;
        res.end(error.message);
    });
}
```

> *... and please provide next time more information about what and how it fails, some logs, inspect response im browser before. And so on..*

Comment: This worked perfectly. This was turning out to be a big headache, thank you so much!